# What is the meaning of this sentence of " the yearling " book?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> The road dropped below him twenty feet down to a little stream.

I think it means that the road goes down 20 feet (it goes to the decent). You know, what makes me confused is *dropped below him 20 feet down*. I can't understand this part! Can you explain it please?

Comment: I'd never read *The Yearling* but unless there's another place in the book where this phrase or one like it occurs, the OP is a misquote. *The east bank  of the road shelved suddenly. It dropped below him twenty feet to a spring.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of saying that a person is **on** a road is "the road below him". We could move the phrase to be immediately after **the road** and it would have the same meaning, and would be a little clearer:

> The road below him dropped twenty feet down to a little stream.

The phrase "down to a little stream" means "downward towards a little stream".

To **drop** can mean "to descend".  When using this phrase of roads (and not of freight elevators, say) the descent is on a *slope*.

The road on which he was traveling descended twenty feet to a little stream.  Presumably he crosses that stream.

I don't think we can be as confident as Peter is that the distance referred to here is vertical.   The stream could easily be twenty feet ahead (down the slope, down the hypotenuse, as it were) and the same words could be used.

Now, if the road was making a kind of steep corkscrew turn (it might be, we don't have enough context to say) then Peter could be correct in his understanding that the vertical distance is being referred to here.

Comment: "twenty feet down" means a vertical drop. A horizontal distance would be "twenty feet ahead".

Comment: Peter,  it *can* mean that but does not necessarily mean that. When the context is the descending slope of a road, the phrase can refer to the horizontal distance. A very possible meaning is "There was a stream twenty feet ahead of him down the slope."  One can easily parse it as "down to a little stream" not "twenty feet down".   Indeed, the latter is not quite idiomatic if referring to a vertical fall.  We don't say of a man who falls from  a ladder "He fell twenty feet down" but "He fell twenty feet".

Comment: Falling from a ladder, you don't need the down because it's redundant. When you fall off a ladder, you almost always fall down. You would say *"He climbed down 20 feet from the window"*, not *"He climbed 20 feet from the window."*

Comment: Why is **down** not redundant with **drop**?  A flaw in your logic? Can we drop up?  We can drop by or drop over, but that is a different sense.

Comment: If they had just said *"The road below him dropped twenty feet to a little stream,"* it wouldn't be clear whether it was twenty feet ahead or twenty feet down. By adding the *down*, it makes it clear that it's a vertical distance of twenty feet.  *Down* isn't redundant here with *drop* (unless you use your interpretation of the sentence).

Comment: The language is not precise enough to support your level of confidence in the interpretation. I will admit your reading as a possibility but not as a necessity.

Comment: And I suppose the horizontal distance reading is possible, but it seems quite unlikely to me.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the road dropped in front of him/before him 20 feet and it leads/comes to a stream.

Comment: *Below* doesn't mean *before*.

Comment: @PeterShor i know

Comment: You have left the subject and verb out of your *that*-clause, so your meaning is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

It means that the road goes down a total of 20 feet vertically from where he's standing (it's not clear how much horizontal distance it takes to do this) and reaches a little stream.